# Log4j2: Suppress only DEBUG messages

Tags: java, xml, logging, log4j, log4j2

I am getting a lot of DEBUG messages in my logs. I want to suppress these, while preserving the INFO and ERROR messages. Here is my log4j2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">

<!-- Author:  Crunchify.com  -->
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d [%t] %5p %c - %m%n" />
        </Console>

        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" filename="test.log"
            filepattern="${LOG_PATH}${LOG_NAME}Log.%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d [%t] %5p %c - %m%n" />
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20" />
        </RollingFile>

         <NoSql name="elasticAppender">
            <Elasticsearch cluster="test" host="test" port="test" index="test" type="log4j2"/>
        </NoSql>


    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="NoSql" />
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
        </Root>

        <Logger name="test" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
        </Logger>

        <Logger name="test" level="info">
        </Logger>

        <Logger name="test" level="INFO">
        </Logger>

        <Logger name="com.datastax.driver.core" level="INFO">
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Does anyone know what change needs to be made here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the Log4j manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html), you might want to change `<Root level="debug">` to `<Root level="info">`.